# Change content in page.tpl.php depending on the page

Tags: views, theming

I am creating a custom Drupal 7 theme and I have an image slider within page.tpl.php, I want to be able to change the images that it is cycling through depending on what page it is on.

I'm using the Views module with Views Slideshow.

If anyone can point me in the correct direction I will be very thankful.

Cheers,

Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already using a View to create your slideshow, could you not [simply use an argument](http://drupal.org/node/54455) to change the View output based on URL? I would need to dig into the specifics of your site to help further, but that seems like the easiest thing to do - no custom functions necessary.

Comment: This is great, why didn't I see this before hand?  I will look into it and get back to you if it worked or not.  But for now, have an upvote. :D

Comment: Thanks! The other simple option, if you have a limited number of pages, is to create multiple view 'blocks', then control their visibility via the normal block controls.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function in your theme template to determine what page you are on...

```
function YOURTHEME_section() {

    $section_path = explode('/', request_uri());
    $section_name = $section_path[1];
    $section_q = strpos($section_name, '?');

    if ($section_q) {
        $section_name = substr($section_name, 0, $section_q);
    }

    switch ($section_name) {
        case '':
            return 'section_home';
            break;
        case 'admin':
            return 'section_admin';
            break;
        default:
            return 'section_404';
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is ( and something I forgot to mention ) is that I need to be able to have the client add images that they want to display on the page.  How would I do that with a function like this? Previously I had a seperate slider for each page, and I had a custom content type for each page called "Page Name Sliding Image", and Views would then bring it in.  I want a less dirty way to do it...

Comment: @Alex I've never seen HOOK_section or THEME_section before. Is this some new thing?

Comment: @LukeBerry the above is just a way to show content depending on what page you are on.

Comment: @Baysaa not a hook just custom that's all.